# Cannot install python both 3.7.3 and 3.7.4 on win10

Tags: python, windows, installation, version

I want to install multiple version of python on my win 10 PC. However If the python [3.7.3](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/python-3.7.3.exe) has already installed I cannot install [3.7.4](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/python-3.7.4.exe) (And vica vera) (Both links are the 32 bit executable installers.).

The following message printed:

**Error 0x80070666: Cannot install a product when a newer version is installed.**

Env:

- OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- Version: 10.0.18362 Build 18362
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz, 3192 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)

Comment: Why do you need both 3.7.3 and 3.7.4? They are basically the same, that's why we call both just "3.7" and executable uses 3.7 in its name, not 3.7.3 or 3.7.4

Comment: Test reasons. I maintain the [wexpect](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect) project, I want to be sure that it can runs on all version of python.